# Laravel Query to retrieve last report id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using this query, I am getting first report id but I want to retrieve latest service report id.

Thanks in advance.

```
 CustomerRequest::where('escalated', '=', 0)
    ->whereIn('customer_request.complain_status_id', array(9, 10))
    ->leftjoin('service_report_mapping', 'service_report_mapping.complain_id', '=', 'customer_request.id')
    ->select('service_report_mapping.report_id')
    ->orderBy('service_report_mapping.report_date', 'DESC')
    ->groupBy('customer_request.id')
    ->get();
```

Output : 
service_report_id
:
20903

Service Report Ids : 20903  47185  87609  98661  98662

98662 is my latest report id.

Comment: are you trying to get the customer request? or the report id?

Comment: I want last report id.

Comment: What is you reports table?

Comment: service_report_mapping table contains report id, report date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Using `max()` I am getting last report id.

Thanks everyone for answers.

```
 CustomerRequest::where('escalated', '=', 0)
    ->whereIn('customer_request.complain_status_id', array(9, 10))
    ->leftjoin('service_report_mapping', 'service_report_mapping.complain_id', '=', 'customer_request.id')
    ->select('max(service_report_mapping.report_id)')
    ->orderBy('service_report_mapping.report_date', 'DESC')
    ->groupBy('customer_request.id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
 CustomerRequest::where('escalated', '=', 0)
    ->whereIn('customer_request.complain_status_id', array(9, 10))
    ->leftjoin('service_report_mapping', 'service_report_mapping.complain_id', '=', 'customer_request.id')
    ->select('service_report_mapping.report_id')
    ->orderBy('service_report_mapping.id', 'DESC')
    ->groupBy('customer_request.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Still I am getting first report id.

Comment: Your table and columns have not any reasonable names. Please give us some information about your table schema and fields and their relation. thanks

Comment: customer request table having complaints and service report mapping contains report ids, these reports are generated for complaints.

Comment: I mean, its better to update your question with tables info like fields and their types.

Answer (score 0):

[Order by](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) `service_report_mapping.id` with `DESC` and the first result is going to be the last ID:

```
 CustomerRequest::where('escalated', '=', 0)
    ->whereIn('customer_request.complain_status_id', array(9, 10))
    ->leftjoin('service_report_mapping', 'service_report_mapping.complain_id', '=', 'customer_request.id')
    ->select('service_report_mapping.report_id')
    ->orderBy('service_report_mapping.id', 'DESC')
    ->groupBy('customer_request.id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

Just put `orderBy` after `groupBy` and check like:

```
CustomerRequest::where('escalated', '=', 0)
    ->whereIn('customer_request.complain_status_id', array(9, 10))
    ->leftjoin('service_report_mapping', 'service_report_mapping.complain_id', '=', 'customer_request.id')
    ->select('service_report_mapping.report_id')
    ->groupBy('customer_request.id')
    ->orderBy('service_report_mapping.report_date', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

**OR**

```
CustomerRequest::where('escalated', '=', 0)
    ->whereIn('customer_request.complain_status_id', array(9, 10))
    ->leftjoin('service_report_mapping', 'service_report_mapping.complain_id', '=', 'customer_request.id')
    ->select('service_report_mapping.report_id')
    ->groupBy('customer_request.id')
    ->orderBy('service_report_mapping.id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: @Nikita Please check my answer and this answer was tested

Comment: Thanks for help. But my problem is 1 customer can have multiple reports and i want last report id for each customer using this it sorted for all customers.

Comment: @Nikita Please display output of this query

Comment: @Nikita So i will more understand your problem and give you fast reply

Answer (score 0):

Not much info given...
Did you try

```
CustomerRequest::where('escalated', '=', 0)
->whereIn('customer_request.complain_status_id', array(9, 10))
->leftjoin('service_report_mapping', 'service_report_mapping.complain_id', '=', 'customer_request.id')
->select('service_report_mapping.report_id')
->latest();
```

?

What was the initial idea behind your groupBy btw? Seems so unnecessary?

Comment: Using groupBy I am getting customer details only one time but one customer having multiple reports so I want to sort that reports of single customer and from that sorted report I want latest report.